# Get npm package name from import through Regex (not relative path)

Tags: regex

I want to get npm package name from import through Regex and should not get relative path

**exclude those matches which are starts from ./**

I tried this: https://regex101.com/r/oyTq9s/1/

```
(?<=from ").+(?=")
```

**Input:**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, Button } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from `@react-navigation/stack`;
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/login";
import CalendarScreen from "./src/screens/Calendar";
import SignUpScreen from "./src/screens/signUp";
import { scale, vs } from "react-native-size-matters";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import UserContext, { UserProvider } from "./src/screens/Context/UserContext";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

**Output should be:**

```
react
react-native
@react-navigation/stack
react-native-size-matters
@react-navigation/drawer
@react-navigation/material-bottom
react-native-elements
@react-navigation/native
```

Comment: Like [`(?<=from ")(?!\./).+?(?=")`](https://regex101.com/r/3R0oDK/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew should also select @react-navigation/stack which is not handling in your regex

Comment: ``(?<=from [`"])(?!\./).+?(?=["`])``?

Comment: `(?:react|@react)[^\`"]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can post your answer

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Sure, I think the second suggestion might even turn out safer, the one with a capturing group and a backreference.

Comment: thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew I think the second option is more safer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex only allows matching from a double quotation mark to the next double quotation mark. You need to add a backtick to each `"`, that is, you need to use a *character class* like `` ["`] `` and you need to exclude those cases where the first `"` or `` ` `` is followed with `./` - you may do that using a *negative lookahead.

Here is an expression that you may use

```
(?<=from [`"])(?!\./).+?(?=["`])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3R0oDK/3).

Or, to ensure there is the same char at the start and end:

```
(?<=from ([`"]))(?!\./).+?(?=\1)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3R0oDK/4).

**Details**

- `` (?<=from ([`"])) ``  - a positive lookbehind that requires `from`, space and then a backtick or a double quotation mark (captured into Group 1) immediately to the right of the current location.
- `(?!\./)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `./` substring immediately to the right of the current location
- `.+?` - any 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\1)` - a positive lookahead that requires the same text as captured in Group 1 immediately to the right of the current location.